# disabling frame resize in Firefox

Tags: firefox, resize, frames, frameset

I have the following frameset:

`<frameset rows="625,*" cols="*" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0" noresize>
    <frame marginheight="0px" src="music-NEW.php" name="mainFrame" scrolling="NO"      frameborder="0" noresize>
    <frame marginheight="0px" src="musicplayer.php" name="bottomFrame" scrolling="NO"   frameborder="0" noresize>
   </frameset>`

in IE the frameset renders how I would like, the appearance of one seamless page. in Firefox, the frameset displays with a grabable bar between the frames and allows grabbing the bar and resizing the frame, which I can't seem to get rid of.

also, why do the frames not line up straight in Firefox and Safari?

Comment: "why do the frames not line up straight in Firefox and Safari?" Show us or explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Add a  noresize="noresize" to your frame:

```
<frame  noresize="noresize">
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want the user not to be able to resize your frames?

WHY?

Do you know, how big his screen is? Do you know, if he/she is disabled and cannot read small letters and has to resize this frame?

In my opinion, you better think about fixed sizes and prohibiting something. Your visitor/user won't be lucky. Nonetheless, he/she will always be able to remove this stupid attribute (Firebug e.g.).

Just my two cents.

Comment: the frames are to make a page that appears as one. allowing the frame to resize is like putting a handle on a div element and allowing the viewer to manipulate the design of the page...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to know [marginwidth and marginheight](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#adef-marginwidth) have to be larger then 0px. Try without that attribute?

> marginwidth = pixels [CN]

This attribute specifies the amount of space to be left between the frame's contents in its left and right margins. The value must be greater than zero (pixels). The default value depends on the user agent.

> marginheight = pixels [CN]

This attribute specifies the amount of space to be left between the frame's contents in its top and bottom margins. The value must be greater than zero (pixels). The default value depends on the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Old question now, but perhaps it would be relevant to use an IFRAME in situations like this.